# mysql get certain rows in order

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get certain rows from a table in order? For Example I have the following rows:

```
EmpID   Name
81      Albert
22      Ashley
71      John
42      Jack
55      Bob
```

Primary Key is EmpID. I want to get only: John, Albert, Bob IN ORDER. Result should be:

```
71      John
81      Albert
55      Bob
```

How can I do that using MySQL query? Thanks heaps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, it use *custom sort*

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE EmpID IN (72,81,55)
ORDER BY FIELD(NAME, 'John', 'Albert', 'Bob')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your SQL statement:

```
ORDER BY CASE EmpID
    WHEN 71 THEN 1  
    WHEN 81 THEN 2  
    WHEN 55 THEN 3  
    ELSE 4
END
```